# Cross-platform development

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html

I was just about to upload my new, redesigned website when I realised "crap, it's just like every other website."

Then I had an idea. And I've spent the past 2 weeks planning. I have but one thing left to do, and it's proving a little difficult to figure out how I can have my website for PC's, and a whole different site for an iPad (or just larger touch based computers in general) and another for Touch-based phones, and then one for regular phones with web browsing capabilities.

Is this possible? I want separation. I don't want a bunch of javascript files with commands for everything inside them. I want to separate each 'website' and serve it based on the platform requesting the document. How can we achieve this?

If you are to recommend any libraries that may help, note that I will not use jQuery (but list jQuery anyway as others who face this problem might not mind using jQuery)

Comment: Look into media types: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: Have you tried googling this? There are tons of examples....

Comment: Yeah I did, but not knowing exactly the right keywords to use doesn't really help much, @Steve.

Comment: Are you looking to develop this or is using an existing CMS ok? I've had very good experiences using Wordpress (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=theme+switcher).

Comment: If you have apache and mod_rewrite enabled this is very easy. Just filter by user agent and send it to your different websites.

Comment: @Iateyourtoothpaste ahh I run into that problem sometimes too. Try this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178619(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ananthonline: I'm developing this. But thanks for the link, I'm sure it'll come in handy in the future.

Comment: Thanks @JacobBlock, that's good to know, though in this case won't be of much help as I'm using shared windows hosting.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use jQuery?

Comment: I'm just sick of it to be honest. I love the idea of it being so simple, but in all honesty, I find it easier to use plain old JavaScript. In saying that, I no longer write JavaScript; I write Typescript (which gets compiled to javascript anyway) - I also find jQuery a little less readable that plain javascript, and having to type a $ every 10 characters is a little too tedious for me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Asp.net MVC and switch your views depending on the device. 
This way you can reuse all your controllers and have different views for each device you want.

Scott Hanselman wrote an article a while ago about this kind of development:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx

I would recommend jQuery Mobile to use in mobile devices. I also recommend Kendo UI Mobile, it really looks amazing but the mobile version is not free..

I also suggest to take a look at SPA (Single Page Applications). With SPA you could have a rich javascript application ready for any device. Combining it with Asp.Net WebApi looks very promising.

Jonh Papa made a course on Pluralsight that is completely worth it:
http://www.johnpapa.net/building-single-page-apps-with-knockout-jquery-and-web-api-ndash-the-story-begins/

It's all about thinking about what you really need and how much effort you can put in.

Answer (score 1):

long answer short, i think what you are looking for is `Request.Browser` to do redirects. You can Access things like Browser.Browser or Browser.Version, i think even a IsMobileDevice is to be found there.

check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx